# Get the List of SharePoint Online Site Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I'm a new SharePoint learner. I would like to list everybody in the site on home page. I've been looking for this over a week but I couldn't find anything.

My goal list list everyone, and filter the birthday or name.

Comment: Is this information in the users' SharePoint profiles?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you are asking. You would like to a create a list of members of you team on the main page or any page.

1. Goto Settings > add an app > custom list
2. before you get started you will need to customize the columns to you liking.
3. Find the list tab > List setting
4. Create Column per your needs
5. once you have this under control go back to you main page.
6. edit page > insert > webparts > apps > YOUR LIST

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can I populate that list?

Comment: @Priyaranjan KS sorry for the late response. The populate option can be done by importing an excel spreadsheet or add item. Keep in mind when importing an excel spreadsheet you have to keep in mind that the fields in the TOP Columns need to be identical. If not you data will be in different spots, which will then require you manually edit the data. <br/>The other option is individually add items by clicking on the 'add item'.

Comment: What I was asking is filling from Sharepoint Online user list. For example filling a dropdown with Sales Group members.